# Complicated recurrence relation of catalan number(from combinatorics test)

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

let
$$a_n^{<m>} \equiv \sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_m = n}a_{k_1}a_{k_2}...a_{k_m}\quad k_i\in \mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\} $$
and $$C_n = \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$
(note that $C_{n+1}=C_n^{<2>}$)

prove for $n\geq3$
$$C_n = \sum_{m = 1}^{n}C_{n-m}^{<m>}$$
he also gave a hint: remember that $C_n$ is the number of "good walk" from $(0,0)$ to $(n,n)$ i try induction but got nowhere

Comment: Are you familiar with generating functions?

Comment: yes but I don't see how to use it here:

Comment: If $A(x)$ is the GF of $a_n$ then $A(x)^m$ is the GF of $a_n^{<m>}$, so the problem can be reduced to a functional equation about the GF of the Catalan numbers. However, I do not know if proving that equation can be done in any easier way than by a counting argument.